# Notifications oreo api 26 - were working perfectly, now they're not

Tags: java, android, notifications

I had notifications working perfectly after implementing channels etc, but then it suddenly stopped working. I'm wondering why, could it be the dependencies, or is there something else wrong with my code?

***Notification code:***

```
 public void initiateNotification(){

    NotificationManager nm = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    builder = new Notification.Builder(this);


    Intent notiIntent = new Intent(this, MainPage.class);
    notiIntent.putExtra("fileName", storage.getFileName(Calendar.getInstance()));
    notiIntent.setAction("NOTI");
    notiIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notiIntent, 0);

    Intent stopIntent = new Intent(this, Services.class);
    stopIntent.setAction("STOP");
    PendingIntent stopPi = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, stopIntent, 0);
    Notification.Action stopAction = new Notification.Action.Builder(null, "STOP", stopPi).build();



    //test
    int notifyID = 1;
    String CHANNEL_ID = "my_channel_01";// The id of the channel.
    CharSequence name = getString(R.string.channel_name);// The user-visible name of the channel.
    int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH;
   NotificationChannel mChannel = new NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID, name, importance);

    Notification noti = new Notification.Builder(Services.this)
            .setContentTitle("Well Done! Stay Active!")
            .setContentText("Number of Steps : " + mSteps)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.bino_small)
            .setContentIntent(pi)
            .setChannelId(CHANNEL_ID)
            .build();


    startForeground(1, noti);
}
```

***SDK versions:***

- compileSdkVersion: 27
- buildToolsVersion: 27.0.3
- minSdkVersion: 26
- targetSdkVersion: 26

I have looked at many solutions and have tried them all, but nothing seems to help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You also need to create the notification channel in case it doesn't exist. (Which is always the case for the first start.)

This can be done with

```
    NotificationManager notificationManager = getSystemService(NotificationManager.class);
    notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
```

Also note that you cannot change the importance anymore after creating the channel.

**Update**

Add the channel creation is done after the initialization of the channel. So this line in your code:

```
NotificationChannel mChannel = new NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID, name, importance);
```

Will become

```
NotificationChannel mChannel = new NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID, name, importance);
NotificationManager notificationManager = getSystemService(NotificationManager.class);
notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(mChannel);
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply!! Where in my code would I insert this notification manager, sorry I'm new to all this  and finding it difficult. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Just after the `NotificationChannel mChannel = new NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID, name, importance);` line, and then call the `createNotificationChannel` with your `mChannel`

Comment: Thanks again for your reply, i really appreciate it. I have added the code below where you said. Now where do I call the createNotificationChannel then? thanks again

Comment: Your welcome, and welcome to Stack Overflow ofcourse! I have updated the answer, does that answer your question?

Comment: Yes perfect, thank you so much for your help, really appreciate it!!